# How know variable name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, var

Suposse an function:

```
function get(){}
```

*this will get an variable*

```
var name = "Eduardo"; 
get(name); 
function get(n) {}
```

And i want to show the name of the variable that was passed, without know this name.

```
function get(n) {
 return getNameVariableFromValue(n); // Pseudocode for explain my question
}
```

*so, i want the name of variable without previouslu knowing this name.*

**PD: My question is mainly to know, who is a variable in the window object, without know this name or value**

Comment: Sounds to me you just want `window.variablename`... Maybe you need to clarify the question.

Comment: your question is not clear. Please add more description to it

Comment: I have already edited

Comment: Code can do a lot, but it's not magic. If you don't know the name or the value of the variable, you simply can't get it. **Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to do and why you feel that you need this kind of a solution?**

Comment: No hablo Espanol. English, por favor.

Comment: How javascript know what is var, const or let? I think that is possible, first i need get the current code of javascript, iterate in the window object, and get  the property that is a var with a regex per example /var[a-z]+/ig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question assumes that no two properties would ever have the same value, which is highly unlikely. But, making that wild assumption, you'd need to make the new `window` property explicitly rather than just declare a global variable and then you could use `Object.keys()` to enumerate all the key names of the `window` object, looking for the one that matches your value. When found, report the key name.

```js
window.myGlobal = "Test";

Object.keys(window).forEach(function(key){

  if(window[key] === "Test"){
    console.log(key);
  }
});
```

This code won't work in the Stack Overflow snippet environment due to sandboxing, but you can see it working **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/hz4eqsnm/4/)** (make sure to have your developer's tools console open when running).

Comment: Scott Marcus, my question says "without previously knowing of the variable name"

Comment: And in the case that the variable was only declarated and not assignated

Comment: @EduardoSebastian If you don't know the name or value, you can't find the variable name.

Comment: var, const and let, have its own characteristics, per e.g let have limited scope, i want to get the name of variable of its characteristics, without know its name or value.

Comment: @EduardoSebastian `var` and `let` don't have any bearing on this. If you don't know the name or the value of a variable, you can't find it later.

Comment: How javascript know if a date is var, let or const ? i want the same behavior.  per example, reading the current javascript code, and find with regex the var keyword

Comment: @EduardoSebastian The variable declaration tells the JavaScript runtime what the scope of the variable (or constant) should be. Once that is set, you can't go back and get the type of declaration back out. It would be better if you just explained what you are really trying to accomplish here. What exactly is the point of getting this information. What's the real issue?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian You are asking for something that is not possible and has no use case. In programming, we really don't care what the name of a variable is because we never need to have the program know it. We only need the program to have the correct values for the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the value as an object to the function and do something like below

```js
function get(n) {
 return Object.keys(n)[0];
}
var name ="Test1";
var name2 = "Test2"
console.log(get({name})) 
console.log(get({name2}))
```

Comment: That's a bit of a cheat isn't it? You might as well just pass the name of the variable as a string to `get()`.